# May I use an already generated artifact from cargo build to run cargo-llvm-cov without recompiling again?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, llvm-cov

### Context

I have a Rust project with a CI set as follow:

1. Job 1 `rust_build`: I build the project and cache the generated artifacts.
2. Job 2 `rust_test`: I download the cache (hence, the artifacts in the `target/` dir), then I run [`cargo llvm-cov`](https://github.com/taiki-e/cargo-llvm-cov/tree/main) to run tests and generate a report.

### Problem

My problem is that the `rust_test` job retriggers a full compilation, I hoped to leverage the already generated artifacts from `rust_build` previous job and spare me a huge time.

### Attempts

1. I tried to copy generated artifacts into `target/llvm-cov-target`
2. I also tried to set-up the `CARGO_LLVM_COV_TARGET_DIR` environment variable directly to `target/` that contains all artifacts from previous `cargo build` (See [Environment variables - cargo-llvm-cov](https://github.com/taiki-e/cargo-llvm-cov#environment-variables)), without success.

I may be missing the whole point, maybe `cargo llvm-cov` **needs** to recompile to work properly but I couldn't find anything.

Is there a solution to use already compiled artifacts to spare some compilation time with `cargo-llvm-cov`?

Comment: I currently tackled this problem by using a specific cache for the build in test mode that I share through branches. I have two builds in cache, it uses more space but it’s a fair tradeoff to spare some compilation time for further branches.